# How to use std::reference_wrapper<T>::operator()

Tags: c++, std

I'd like to use the `std::reference_wrapper<T>::operator()` "the same" as `std::reference_wrapper<T>::get`, but following [example](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/azf957MeG) fails for `operator()`

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <functional>

class Foo {
public:
  void Print() {
    std::printf("Foo\n");
  }
};

class Bar {
public:
  Bar(Foo &foo): wrapper{foo} {}
  void Print() {
    wrapper.get().Print();  // OK
    // wrapper().Print();   // FAIL
  }
private:
  std::reference_wrapper<Foo> wrapper;
};

int main() {
  Foo foo{};
  Bar bar{foo};
  bar.Print();
  return 0;
}
```

Is this possible? Where is my misunderstanding?

Thanks for the help

Zlatan

Comment: Please, have a look into the [doc.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper): get ... accesses the stored reference, operator() ... _calls the stored function_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this possible? Where is my misunderstanding?

No. `std::reference_wrapper<T>::operator()` only exists when `T::operator()` exists, and it simply calls that, forwarding the arguments provided.

Are you mistaking it for `std::reference_wrapper<T>::operator T&`?

```
class Bar {
public:
  Bar(Foo &foo): wrapper{foo} {}
  void Print() {
    Foo & f = wrapper;
    f.Print()
  }
private:
  std::reference_wrapper<Foo> wrapper;
};
```

Comment: Indeed, I mistaking it for `std::reference_wrapper<T>::operator T&` :( Anyway, thanks for the answer

Answer (score 3):

`operator()` of `std::reference_wrapper` does *not* do the same as `.get()`.

Its `operator()` invokes a function or other *Callable* object to which the stored reference refers.

In your example a `Foo` object is not a *Callable*. If `Print` was instead `operator()`, then you could simply call it with

```
wrapper();
```